# How to implement WCF test client for non windows platform.

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I have been evaluating and working on a prototype where I have exposed couple of API using WCF web service. My service is working as expected with managed client in windows platform. My service client can be on any platform. I dont know how to approach for other platform (UNIX). Couple of options I have considered so far -

- GSOAP
- MONO dotnet

I could not use any one of these due to some constraints. Now the only option I left out to implement my own client which can send soap request and get soap response. My preferred technology is C/C++. I am using wsHttpBinding in my server and will be working on http protocol only. 
I am not sure about the following points-

1. Do I need to implement my own WSDL parser?
2. Do I need my own serializer?
3. How could I make my client more flexible so that any changes in my WSDL make minimal code changes on client side?

I am looking for help from the experts who could guide me with a proper approach with a basic client sample.

Comment: [Have you had a look at SoapUI?](http://www.soapui.org/) - it's an open-source, Java-based SOAP client that can easily be used to test your WCF services. There is a free version available (and a Pro version with more features which costs a moderate fee)

Answer (score 0):

My experience is in WCF interoperability with Java clients. You can use Java SOAP libraries like metro http://metro.java.net/ or axis http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/index.html . There is even a C library for axis. http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/

I am sure other languages like Ruby/Python etc has similar libraries as well.

The other option is to use a REST based interface and then you can use any language/platform that has HTTP support or even a tool like curl and libcurl http://curl.haxx.se/.

Comment: I could not use java as the the client application is in C++. If I deliver a java library then the client need a bridge (JNI) which will increase the complexity. And the maintenance will also be tough. My service is not a huge one and has less no of APIs. So if I want to implement my client proxy in C/C++, what will be the approach? Is there any framework or library available to do the job?

Comment: I haven't used but you may investigate the axis2/C which is a C library and hence should be usable from C++